# TO_CHAR for date timefield, group by alters output

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, count

I have a sql query where I am using count, case etc. but when I added date field to be returned, my counts are changed, and I don't want my output to be that way. Can you suggest a better way of approaching this?

```
Select A, b, C, D, (CASE when tablename.FIeldname when T then (count(tableName.Fieldname) - 1) ELSE 0 END) as TEST_1, 
       To_char(dateTimefield, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
from table name
where <<>>
group by A, B, C, D, tableName.field Name, date field
```

This changed my counts from case in column 5, without date field my output is just like I want - but I need the date.

Comment: Please include the actual query/code you are running.  What you posted in your question won't even compile on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Then remove the date from the `group by`.  Instead use an aggregation function:

```
Select A, b, C, D, (CASE when tablename.FIeldname when T then (count(tableName.Fieldname) - 1) ELSE 0 END) as TEST_1, 
       To_char(min(dateTimefield), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
from table name
where <<>>
group by A, B, C, D, tableName.field Name
```